# Eclipse Oxygen's Text Font setting and those derived from it are not respected

Tags: eclipse, text, fonts, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-oxygen

I installed the latest [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/oxygen1a) (Windows 64-bit) recently.

When changing *Text Font* to my personal preference I realized that this setting and those derived from it (*C/C++ Editor Text font*, *C/C++ Build Console Text Font*, *Structured Text Editor Text Font*) are not respected in *Generic Text Editor*, *Text Editor*, *C/C++ Editor*, *XML Editor*.

Funny thing is: If I <kbd>Reset</kbd> *Text Font* the font name in the *Preview* below is empty(!), just the font size is displayed there and the text preview's font is the font that's used in all the editors mentioned above.

Is this a (known?) bug or what am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

Preferences:

[image: Preferences]

This is NOT Courier New:

[image: NOT Courier New]

Comment: It works for me in the same Eclipse package and version. Do you have a theming plug-in installed?

Comment: @howlger No, I don't have anything installed additionaly.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot to your question for better understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and extracted the package once again and now the font preferences work as usual.